# Problem including nav_msgs/msg/odometry

Tags: ros, nav-msgs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

when using the message type nav_msgs/msg/odometry (https://docs.ros2.org/foxy/api/nav_msgs/msg/Odometry.html) I tried o include it using this piece of code:

```
#include <nav_msgs/msg/odometry.h>
```

In the CMakeList.txt I added `find_package(nav_msgs REQUIRED)` and in the package.xml I added `<depend>nav_msgs</depend>` so this should cause no problems. Even the command `ros2 interface show nav_msgs/msg/Odometry`
returnes the expected output.

When building the package in the same prompt it says `fatal error: nav_msgs/msg/odometry.h: No such file or directory`

Can anyone help me with this?

Regards s0nc

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/390319/problem-including-nav_msgs/msg/odometry/) by [s0nc](https://answers.ros.org/users/88613/s0nc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2021-11-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The correct file to include is `nav_msgs/msg/odometry.hpp`.

---

Originally posted by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) with karma: 4203 on 2021-11-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [s0nc](https://answers.ros.org/users/88613/s0nc/) on 2021-11-09**:
Thank you, it finally works :)